# Updating aws glue catalog table with glue api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to use create table glue api to create the data catalog and thus bypassing the need of crawler because the schema is going to be same every-time.

I am able to create the data catalog and now whenever any updated csv file comes in s3 , the table is updated (as in when i run the athena query it shows the updated table).

But my problem is , that there are cases when i will get only the deltas ( that is only the data which is changed and not a complete data ) , now when only the deltas are coming , and when i am running the athena query manually on the table, it is only showing the deltas , and data is not getting merged with the earlier complete data.
So i am not understanding how shall i update only deltas and merge then in the original data catalog.

**Is it even possible with aws glue???**

### Below is my current code:-

```
import boto3
import json

client=boto3.client('glue')
def lambda_handler(event, context):

response = client.create_table(
DatabaseName = 'sample',
TableInput = {

'Name': 'lawyertable4',
'Description': 'Table created with boto3 API',
'StorageDescriptor': {
    'Columns': [{
            'Name': 'id',
            'Type': 'bigint',
        
        },
        {
            'Name': 'username',
            'Type': 'string',
            
        },
        {
            'Name': 'time_stamp',
            'Type': 'string',
        
        },
        
    ],
    'Location': 's3://location/sample/',
    'InputFormat': 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat',
    'OutputFormat': 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat',
    'Compressed': False,
    'SerdeInfo': {
        'SerializationLibrary': 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe',
        'Parameters': {
                'field.delim': ',',
                'skip.header.line.count':'1'
                
            }
    }
},
 }
 )
```

Comment: Have you tried running msck repair table tablename this updated the metadata in the catalog

Comment: How are you calculating the delta ? Are you using Glue bookmarking ? Also when writing output to s3 what mode you are writing in ?